# RTEMS Not Building?

Tags: cross-compiling, sparc, rtems

I am trying to get RTEMS to compile via the directions listed at:

https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/TBR/UserManual/Quick_Start

I have used the "RTEMS Source Builder" to produce a cross compiler suite for the SPARC architecture:

https://docs.rtems.org/rsb/

My directory structure is as follows:

```
|RTEMS_OS
    |
    |build
    |
    |dist
    |
    |Source
```

I obtained RTEMS v4.12 via git:

```
git clone git://git.rtems.org/rtems.git ./Source
```

I am using the following script to build RTEMS:

```
export RTEMS_CROSS_TOOLS_PREFIX=/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_Cross_Tools/dist/SPARC
export RTEMS_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/dist/SPARC
export RTEMS_TARGET_ARCH=sparc-rtems4.12
export RTEMS_BOARD_SUPPORT_PACKAGE=sis

##################################################
PROJECT_DIR=${PWD}
export PATH=${RTEMS_CROSS_TOOLS_PREFIX}/bin:${PATH}


if [! -f ../Source/configure]; then
pushd Source
    echo "Running bootstrap to generate configure files..."
    echo 
    ./bootstrap 2>&1 | tee ${PROJECT_DIR}/bootstrap.log
    echo "Bootstrap operation complete..."
    echo 
popd

read -n 1 -p "Any key to continue, ^c to Terminate..." userinput
fi

pushd build
    echo "Configuring RTEMS OS..."
    echo 
    ../Source/configure \
        --target=${RTEMS_TARGET_ARCH} \
        --enable-rtemsbsp=${RTEMS_BOARD_SUPPORT_PACKAGE} \
        --prefix=${RTEMS_INSTALL_PREFIX} \
        --enable-tests=samples \
        2>&1 | tee ${PROJECT_DIR}/configure.log

    echo "Configure opteration complete."
    echo 
popd

read -n 1 -p "Any key to continue, ^c to Terminate..." userinput

pushd build
    echo "Building RTEMS OS..."
    echo 
    make 2>&1 | tee ${PROJECT_DIR}/build.log
    echo "Build opteration complete."
    echo 
popd

read -n 1 -p "Any key to continue, ^c to Terminate..." userinput

pushd build
    echo "Installing RTEMS OS..."
    echo 
    make install 2>&1 | tee ${PROJECT_DIR}/install.log
    echo "Install opteration complete."
    echo 
popd
```

Here is my make file output:

```
build.log

Making all in tools/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/build'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/build'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/build'
Making all in tools/cpu
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/cpu'
Making all in generic
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/cpu/generic'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/cpu/generic'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/cpu'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/cpu'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/tools/cpu'
Making all in testsuites/tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/testsuites/tools'
Making all in generic
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/testsuites/tools/generic'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/testsuites/tools/generic'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/testsuites/tools'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/testsuites/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/testsuites/tools'
Making all in sparc-rtems4.12/c
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/sparc-rtems4.12/c'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/sparc-rtems4.12/c'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/sparc-rtems4.12/c'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build/sparc-rtems4.12/c'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xubuntu/Development/RTEMS/RTEMS_OS/build'
```

The make and make install steps complete very quickly (less than a second) and after it all there are no built test samples or RTEMS files from what I can tell.

Ideally I am wanting to do this for my true target architecture, but I just thought I would try to get the sample working and adapt it, but I am completely stuck after several attempts. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake and lesson learned. Read the notes and warnings carefully.

"WARNING: Replace 4.11 with the proper version. Also for 4.11 and older, use the sis BSP. **For 4.12 and newer, use the erc32 BSP**."

https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/TBR/UserManual/Quick_Start